# JSON payload validates against schema even though field is missing

Tags: javascript, json

I assume I've missed something in defining the schema. Note that the `id` property is required under the `form` property, but it is not provided in the JSON, yet the JSON validates correctly according to multiple JSON validators online.

**Schema**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.biz",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "form": {
      "type": "object",
      "nullable": false,
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "The unique identifier of the form.",
          "nullable": false
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the form.",
          "nullable": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON Payload**

```
{
  "form": {
    "name": "Test 2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema doesn't specify which properties are `required`.  You need to set `required` to the fields you want to be there.  You may also wish to set `additionalProperties` to `false`.

Docs: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties

I don't see `nullable` as a key anywhere in the json schema docs.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.biz",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "form": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "The unique identifier of the form."
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the form."
        }
      },
      "required": ["id", "name"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the library I'm using is out of date, perhaps...adding those fields as `required` works.